# Update entity does not update Navigation Property - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to update a relationship using Entity Framework, but I don't have success.

I have a entity called Houses and these House are on a Street.

Streets can have many Houses.

I use this to update the values of Houses

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Houses house)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            house.Color = "Yellow";
            house.Street.Id = 2; //It does not update, why?

            db.HousesSet.Attach(house);

            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(house, EntityState.Modified);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(house);
    }
```

and the house values are edited, except by the Navigation property, I wasn't successful in changing the relationship with street, I'd like to change the house street.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it from the street object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Houses house)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var street = db.Street.Include("Houses").Where(c => c.Id == house.Street.Id).FirstOrDefault;
        street.Houses.Add(new House{ houseSfuffGoesHere});
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    //whatever else you wanted to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Id property set to be generated by the database in the mapping?

If you have marked the property with the attribute DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity, it won't be saved.

Alternatively if you are trying the change the actual street object, then you should load the street object you want and assign that the property as fillows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Houses house)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var street = db.StreetsSet.First(2);
        house.Color = "Yellow";

        house.Street = street;

        db.HousesSet.Attach(house);

        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(house, EntityState.Modified);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(apartamentos);
}
```